# How does Veracrypt work?

Tags: encryption, hash, key, veracrypt

I’m a layman in security and was trying to understand how hashes and encryption algorithms are used in Veracrypt/Truecrypt.

Reading the documentation, this is what I understood (please, feel free to correct me if I’m wrong):

For simplification’s sake, let’s consider a non-system volume, no hidden volumes and no Cascade.

An encrypted **HEADER** is generated containing two **Master Keys** (Primary and Secondary). Those **Master Keys** were created using **RNG** based on the **HASH**.

To *Decrypt* the **HEADER**, the correct password must generate a **HEADER KEY** (two keys, actually) using a *derivation function* from the selected **HASH Algorithm**.

This HEADER KEY decrypts the HEADER. In other words, the HEADER is not the HASH itself from which the key is compared with.

**Edit**: The [documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Header%20Key%20Derivation.html) explains how the **Header Key Derivation** is done:

> 12-bit salt is used, which means there are 2512 keys for each password. This significantly decreases vulnerability to 'off-line' dictionary/'rainbow table' attacks (pre-computing all the keys for a dictionary of passwords is very difficult when a salt is used) [7]. The salt consists of random values generated by the VeraCrypt random number generator during the volume creation process. The header key derivation function is based on HMAC-SHA-512, HMAC-SHA-256, HMAC-RIPEMD-160, or HMAC-Whirlpool (see [8, 9, 20, 22]) – the user selects which. The length of the derived key does not depend on the size of the output of the underlying hash function. For example, a header key for the AES-256 cipher is always 256 bits long even if HMAC-RIPEMD-160 is used (in XTS mode, an additional 256-bit secondary header key is used; hence, two 256-bit keys are used for AES-256 in total).

Also, about the [decryption](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Encryption%20Scheme.html), it says:

> Decryption is considered successful if the first 4 bytes of the decrypted data contain the ASCII string “VERA”, and if the CRC-32 checksum of the last 256 bytes of the decrypted data (volume header) matches the value located at byte #8 of the decrypted data (this value is unknown to an adversary because it is encrypted – see the section VeraCrypt Volume Format Specification). If these conditions are not met, the process continues from (3) again, but this time, instead of the data read in (1), the data read in (2) are used (i.e., possible hidden volume header). If the conditions are not met again, mounting is terminated (wrong password, corrupted volume, or not a VeraCrypt volume).

If this is correct, I have some questions:

1. Is the *encryption method* of the **HEADER** the same of the rest of the volume? And only the keys are different…
2. If I got it correctly, the two **HEADER Keys** are 256 bit longer. Does those two combined key have the same power as a single 512 bits longer hash? Or is it equivalent to 2^256 + 2^256?
3. If not for (2), what’s the point of selecting a 512 bits **HASH Algorithm**?
4. If yes for (2), does the subsequent two **Master Keys** also have 512-bit long equivalent power?
5. Does the subsequent **two Master Keys** also uses the same **HASH algorithm** that **HEADER Keys** uses? For instance, if I select *Whirlpool algorithm* in the *wizard*, does it only affects the HEADER KEY or both?

Comment: It would be "2^256 * 2^256", not "2^256 + 2^256" (unless your `+` means concatenation of bits).